# Configure Webpack loader to work within node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

I am trying to use an npm package called [`@use-gpu/workbench`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@use-gpu/workbench), which contains `.wgsl` files that need to be processed using the Webpack loader [`@use-gpu/wgsl-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@use-gpu/wgsl-loader).

Following [the documentation](https://usegpu.live/docs/guides-getting-started#:%7E:text=return%20null%3B%0A%7D%3B-,WGSL%20Loader,-To%20use%20%40use), which specifies how to configure webpack, I added the following code to my `next.config.js`:

```
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    // ...

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.wgsl$/,
      use: ["@use-gpu/wgsl-loader"],
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**This configuration works correctly for importing `.wgsl` files in user code.**

However, I get the following errors when the `.wgsl` file being imported lives within `node_modules/@use-gpu/workbench`:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at /Users/pulljosh/Code/graphing-calculator/node_modules/ (use-gpu/wgsl/render/pick.wgsl:1)
```

How can I apply my Webpack loader to `node_modules` as well?

---

A few other things I tried that **didn't work**:

- Setting `transpilePackages: ["@use-gpu/wgsl"]` in my Next.JS config
- Doing the same as the above bullet point but using the `next-transpile-modules` package instead.
- Adding

  ```
  config.resolve.modules.push(
    path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "@use-gpu", "wgsl")
  );
  ```

  to the Next.js Webpack config
- Adding the `include` option to the loader rule:

  ```
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.wgsl$/i,
    use: ["@use-gpu/wgsl-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules", "@use-gpu", "wgsl"),
  });
  ```

No combination of any of the above options worked for me.